# C# Determine how a row/data is added to a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a use case where I am showing data from database in DataGridView, but when I add new rows on the UI (there is no code for adding new row, when I click the button I get all rows from DataGridView - old ones from database and new ones added on the UI), I need to know what rows are added from the UI. Is there a way to know it without checking in database and comparing it? I would like to know it from the UI. I have tried with ISNewRow() but it is true only for the last row.

Comment: Preferably a small set of code involving loading the DataGridView will help answer your question as there are several distinct ways to load a DataGridView.

Comment: The `DataGridView` has several events that are triggered when a new row is added to the grid… [DataGridView.RowsAdded Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) … may be what you are looking for. It is unclear how the grid is filled and I assume possibly a `DataTable` may be used as a `DataSource` to the grid. In that case, the `DataTable` has a `GetChanges` method that may work. Have you looked at a `DataAdapter`?

Comment: I suggest you peruse the SO [tour] section as it shows how SO works. The [ask] section may help. In addition, you may find the SO [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section useful.

Answer (score 1):

When using a DataGridView people tend to fiddle with rows and cells directly. Although this is possible, it is way more easy to use data binding via property DataSource.

Using the visual studio designer, you have added a DataGridView and the columns that you want to show. Although it is possible to define which column should show which property, it is easier to do this in the constructor.

Alas you forgot to tell us what items you want to show, so let's assume you want to show several properties of a `Product`:

```
class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}
    public int Stock {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Suppose you want to show these values as columns in your DataGridView. In the constructor you'll write:

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();  // Creates the DataGridView and the columns

    // define which column should show which property
    this.ColumnId.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.Id);
    this.ColumnDescription.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.Description);
    this.ColumnPrice.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.Price);
    this.ColumnStock.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.Stock);
    ... // etc, for all Product properties that you want to show
}
```

Somewhere, you'll have a method to fetch the products from the database:

```
private IEnumerable<Product> FetchProductsToDisplay()
{
    ... // TODO: implement; out of scope of this question
}
```

To display Products: assign them via a `BindingList<Product>` to the DataSource of the DataGridView:

```
private BindingList<Product> DisplayedProducts
{
    get => (BindingList<Product>)this.DataGridView1.DataSource;
    set => this.DataGridView1.DataSource = value;
}
```

At loading form, or after some other event, you need to fill the datagridview with the Products:

```
private void InitializeTableProducts()
{
    IEnumerable<Product> productsToDisplay = this.FetchProductsToDisplay();
    this.DisplayedProducts = new BindingList<Product>(productsToDisplay.ToList());
}
```

This is enough to display the Products. The operator can add / remove Products, and edit Cells, according to the editability you defined in the columns and the datagridview. If allowed he can even rearrange the rows and columns.

When the operator has finished editing, he notifies the software for instance by pressing the OK button:

```
private void OnButtonOk_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    this.ProcessEditedProducts();
}

private void ProcessEditedProducts()
{
    ICollection<Product> editedProducts = this.DisplayedProducts;
    this.ProcessProducts(editedProducts);
}
```

In ProcessProducts, you'll have to find out which Products are added / removed / changed. I assume you'll recognize an edited product by a zero Id.

To find out if a Product is removed: it will have an Id in the original database, but not in the editedProducts.

Changed Products are more difficult: you need to compare by value. For this you need to create an `IEqualityComparer<Product>`.

I'll assume you know the techniques how to check if the Product is added / removed / changed.